# DST restoration under Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, datetime, dst

I have date/time information from Berlin,Germany.
For example:
2011-05-16 12:24:23,
2011-01-21 17:00:31

Unfortunatly, these times have NO daylight saving information. I know that the first date is CEST and the second time is CET.

I could write a check whether the date/time is daylight saving or not.

The summertime starts at the last sunday in march at 2:00 AM, and ends at the last sunday in october at 3 AM.

Self developing such a check seems error prone to me. Is there something that can be already used under Linux in C?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the time to a `time_t` with `mktime()` and then pass it back in to `localtime()` which will set `tm_isdst`. Both `mktime()` and `localtime()` utilize your local system's time configuration, so you're really discovering if the timestamp is in DST **where you are**.  The obvious problem here is that you have a timestamp string without geographical information so the best you can do is assume it's for your current location.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `%Z` format argument to the [date](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command to obtain the timezone from a date, then determine if DST was in effect from the timezone's name:

```
$ date -d '2011-05-16' '+%Z'
CEST

$ date -d '2011-01-21' '+%Z'
CET
```